# How to replace request param name using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'd like to rewrite part of URLS like:

```
/api/posts?topic.id=246&pagination=false
```

to

```
/api/posts?postTopics.topic.id=246&pagination=false
```

`topic.id => postTopics.topic.id`

Please help.

Comment: is `topic.id` always an integer?

Comment: yes, `topic.id` always an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !postTopics.topic.id=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)topic.id=([0-9]*)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1postTopics.topic.id=%2%3 [QSD,NE]
```